# Storing a div contents into an array and retrieving it back

Tags: jquery

I was trying to save a div into an array and trying to retrieve it back later.
I am saving it when the user unchecks a checkbox and try to retrieve the div contents when he checks it again here is the code

```
myDivBackups = new Array();

function backupMydiv(myDivID) {
    myDivBackup = {};
    var isExist = false;
    myDivBackup['name'] = myDivID;
    myDivBackup['html'] = $(myDivID);

    for (var index in myDivBackups) {
        if (myDivBackups[index].name == myDivID) {
            isExist = true;
            break;
        } else {
            isExist = false;
        }
    }
    if (isExist === false) {
        myDivBackups.push(myDivBackup);
    }
    //clearing the textboxes in dom
    $(myDivID).find('input:text').val('');

}
//restoring div contents by taking from myDivbackups array
function restoreMydiv(myDivID) {
    for (var index in myDivBackups) {
        if (myDivBackups[index].name === myDivID) {
            var temp = myDivBackups[index].html;
            return (temp[0]);
            //in temp[0] i am getting div contents with cleared inputs
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really understand how javascript is taking care of it , I get the logs right ( I am getting the div contents) but textboxes are getting cleared every time.

thanks.

Edit : here is the div which I am trying to save

```
<div id="mydiv_4" class="mydiv_values" style="display: block;"> 
     <div class="mySubdiv">
        <span class="myvalue_title">Values</span>
        <input type="button" id="add_value" class="blue" value="Add Value">
        <label class="my-text" id="caption_text">my Text</label>
        <input type="text" name="mytext_4" class="my-text-value" value="">
        <p><input type="text" id="1" name="myinput_4_1" value="1"></p> 
        <p><input type="text" id="2" name="myinput_4_2" value="2"></p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add your html too.

Comment: //clearing the textboxes - well u have $(myDivID).find('input:text').val(''); that clear the value.

Comment: @petroff but before that I am pushing the contents of div into an array

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but wouldn't it be easier to just toggle() them?

Comment: myDivBackup['html'] = $(myDivID); thats not the html. its jquery selectro. try with myDivBackup['html'] = $(myDivID).html();

Comment: @BitwiseCreative I need to clear the data and hide , I need it cleared if its hidden in server side for rest of the manipulations

Comment: @Petroff  tried that also , I am getting the contents from array anyway .. but the problem is inputs are cleared ..

Comment: Try to get only values in json object and then clear. When he click checkbox again put values from json in inputs. Its not that you want to do, but can resolve the problem.

Comment: @Petroff adding $(myDivID).html(); worked !! thank you ! plese post that comment as answer , sorry but the clearing inputs dont work now Ill check that ....but thank you agin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $(myDivID).html(); to get the html :)